# Unable to call Proxy API on server for Nuxtjs

Tags: proxy, nuxt.js

I am not able to call proxy url which I setup in target field in nuxt.config.js.

Sample code:

Nuxt.config.js:

```
modules: [ '@nuxtjs/proxy' ],
```

```
proxy: {
```

```
'/api/ :{
```

```
target: 'some external API Endpoint / URL',pathRewrite: { '^/api/' : '/' },
```

```
changeOrigin: true
```

```
}
```

```
}
```

Above setup working fine in localhost, but when I create dist folder and deploy to server and run from the server, it is actually tried to fetch resource from server, not from proxy end point.

Let me know how to fix this issue, so my proxy URL will start working on server.

I tried above configuration and working fine in localhost, but when I deployed the same code to server it is not working.